# Dynamically create Angular component from string

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

My goal is to create an automatic way of transforming any given string part of an HTML element into a custom component.

For example, given:

```
<p> Hello my name is #max </p>
```

I would like to create something like:

```
<p> Hello my name is <some-custom-component name="Max"></some-custom-component> </p>
```

which will then be rendered based on `some-custom-component`'s template

My main issue it to wrap the custom component with all the extra content of the HTML element itself. I know I can create the component using [Angular Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader) but I'm not able to get a suitable templateRef for it

The ideal solution would be:

1. User can attach my directive to any HTML element specifying a pattern
2. The directive scans the content replacing any occurrence of the pattern with a custom component (statically or dynamically chosen doesn't matter)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue now, how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's funny. Sorry I'm late for this since you probably already solved it, but I've written a library that so perfectly fits your use case that I wouldn't be surprised if I saw this post, somehow got Amnesia and then subsconsciously started working on solving the problem.

Anyway, the library is called [ngx-dynamic-hooks](https://github.com/MTobisch/ngx-dynamic-hooks). Check out the "[Writing your own HookParser](https://github.com/MTobisch/ngx-dynamic-hooks#7-writing-your-own-hookparser)"-section especially (if for some reason, it is still useful to you).

Comment: Nice. I solved differently in the end but your library looks great and I'll give it a try anyway! Thank you